# Strange behaviour: json_encode() producing invalid json dependent on input

Tags: php, json, syntax, syntax-error, quotes

today I had to deal with some veeeery strange behaviour of php's **json_encode()**, that I could nowhere read about.

### In short:

1. Fetching a row of the database
2. Building a **stdClass**-object and storing some of the data in there
3. Encoding it using json_encode()

   ```
   $obj = new stdClass();
   $obj->a = "foo";
   $obj->b = "bar";
   $obj->c = "doo";
   $obj->d = "baa";
   json_encode( $obj );
   ```

## The Problem:

The returned JSON was buggy: a second (the last one, but only this one!) variable was merged with into the string value of the previous one.

For example it looked like:

```
{"a": "foo", "b": "bar", "c": "doo', 'd': 'baa"}
                                  ^-------^
```

Of course I've var_dumped() the object I'm passing over to json_encode()... nothing! Everything was fine and exactly as expected. All the vars were correct and all the values were strings.

But well, that's not enough. Playing around with that, I found out, that changing the order in wich I'm storing the values into the object solved the problem:

```
$obj->d = "baa";
$obj->c = "doo";
```

Did not produce an error.

For now I just changed the order of the columns of the database table. But I would like to know, where this never-seen bug comes from and eventually report it.

The bug only appeared on a Debian-VM running PHP 5.3.6. Another VM running PHP 5.3.3 produced correct JSON, just like Mac OS X Lion's integrated webserver running PHP 5.3.8.

## My Question

### Does anyone experience this problem also?

Greetings from Germany!

#### The original code

```
$obj = new stdClass();
$obj->Id = '35';
$obj->EventsCategories_Id = '8';
$obj->Name = 'Blubber';
$obj->OrderValue = '2';
var_dump($obj);
json_encode($obj);
```

Comment: I just tested this on PHP 5.3.8 and I can confirm got the correct output `string(41) "{"a":"foo","b":"bar","c":"doo","d":"baa"}"`.  Just throwing this out there to confirm that 5.3.8 is working correctly.

Comment: I just installed PHP 5.3.6 (CLI, Windows, VC9) to run your same code and original code on and I still got the correct output.  I tried both the thread-safe and non thread-safe versions and still got the same results.

Comment: Can you post what the results of `var_dump($obj)` and `var_dump(json_encode($obj))` are in your environment?

Comment: Nice question/formatting. But can't reproduce it either with `5.3.6-13ubuntu3.6+suhosin` (which is close to your Debian build). You should definitely file this as bug on [php.net](https://bugs.php.net/search.php?search_for=json_encode&boolean=0&limit=300&order_by=&direction=DESC&cmd=display&status=All&bug_type=All&project=All&php_os=&phpver=&cve_id=&assign=&author_email=&bug_age=0&bug_updated=0) and [debian.org](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/pkgreport.cgi?pkg=php5;dist=unstable).

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea about whether this will help or not, but does running the following code produce any different results?

```php
$obj = new stdClass();
$obj->Id = '35';
$obj->EventsCategories_Id = '8';
$obj->Name = 'Blubber';
$obj->OrderValue = '2';

// convert the stdClass object to an array
$obj = (array) $obj;
var_dump($obj);
json_encode($obj);
```

I think the pertinent question to ask is whether this is:

- an internal PHP issue (possible, but unlikely)
- a problem arising from some environmental issue (a conflicting library?)
- a missing configuration option

While I highly doubt that you've done something wrong (I mean, this is a simple use-case and there's nothing wrong with your code at all), perhaps you could try a couple of other things...

For example, try appending a 2nd argument to the `json_encode` function:

`echo json_encode($obj, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);`

Could you post the results of these two short experiments? This problem is quite strange, indeed. I'm running PHP 5.3.1 and it generates syntactically correct JSON based on your example - no problems to report.